# Redireccion 301 Htacces

Tags: .htaccess, redirección

Un cliente en un principio quiso que su pagina web mostrara /shop al final de su url, ahora quiere que no lo muestre, tiene esto en su htacces que coloco en un principio. Su hosting es compartido tiene la web en una carpeta /shop y la url del dominio www.dominio.com parkeada a esa carpeta

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dominio\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.dominio\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/dominio\.com\/shop\/" [R=301,L]
```

Como quitaria la redireccion que muesta /shop/ en la url y que no afecte las urls ya indexadas?

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/dominio\.com\/shop\/" [R=301,L]
```

Deberia quedar asi?

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/dominio\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

o eliminar el RewriteRule y añadir

```
Redirect 301 /shop http://www.dominio.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

**NOTA:** Si tu pagina aun no esta en uso, solo tienes que quitar la `RewriteRule`

---

Ahora bien, si ya tienes cierto peso ganado en buscadores, para mantenerlo la mejor opcion es la 2a: hacer un redirect 301.

Traducido de [AQUI](http://www.webconfs.com/how-to-redirect-a-webpage.php)

> El redirect 301 redirect es el metodo más eficiente y compatible con los motores de busqueda para redirecciones web. No es difícil de implementar y **preservara las posiciones en los motores de busqueda de cada página** en particular. **Si tienes que** cambiar nombres de fichero o **mover páginas, esta es la opcion más segura.** El codigo 301 es interpretado como "movido permanentemente.

---

En cambio, `RewriteRule` se usa precisamente para eso, para sobreescribir urls existentes con otra dirección, no influye si quieres conservar el peso de la url en los motores de busqueda ya que digamos que creara una especie de alias que cojerá peso propio.

Comment: Deberia entonces colocarlo asi? RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dominio\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.dominio\.com$
Redirect 301 /shop http://www.dominio.com/ [R=301,L]